i wanted to install some wine dependencies but when ever i type sudo apt update this brave browser stopping me from completing it
W: GPG error: https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0686B78420038257
E: The repository 'https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
user@shadow:~/Desktop$
